# Pass Text and Inputs Without Specifying Each as a Variable

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have the following form on form.html, a regular html page.

```
<form action="confirmation.cfm" name="myform">

What is 1+1<br>
<input type="text" value=""><br><br>

What is 2+2<br>
<input type="text" value=""><br><br>

What is 3+3<br>
<input type="text" value=""><br><br>

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

When this form is submitted, I want all of the questions and the text put in the associated input boxes to be submitted to a ColdFusion page and just displayed. Without having to specify the variable name for each question and each input, is there a way I can pass this information, maybe by just using the form name, myform?

In otherwords, if a user put in the answers to each of the questions, 2, 4, 6 and submitted the form on form.html, I'd like confirmation.cfm, to display the following:

What is 1+1
2

What is 2+2
4

What is 3+3
6

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use form scope. FORM scope at as structure and you can easily loop through it. May be below code will help.

```
<cfloop collection="#form#" item="lc">
    <cfoutput>#form[lc]#<br/></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add name's to INPUTs, because server need to distinguish them somehow

cannot check for syntax errors, but you should do something like this:

```
<cfparam name="num1" default="">
<cfparam name="num2" default="">
<cfparam name="num3" default="">

<form action="confirmation.cfm" name="myform">
What is 1+1<br>
<input type="text" value="" name="num1"><br>
<cfoutput>#num1#</cfoutput><br>
What is 2+2<br>
<input type="text" value="" name="num2"><br>
<cfoutput>#num2#</cfoutput><br>
What is 3+3<br>
<input type="text" value="" name="num3"><br>
<cfoutput>#num3#</cfoutput><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not looking for them to be distinguished, I want them all to be treated as one variable. That includes the questions themselves.

Comment: how you can treat 3 different values as one variable?

Comment: @Mike you can pull everything by dumping out the `form` scope.

Comment: I want to say I've seen it before, but I don't recall how. Wasn't sure if it was in the realm of possibility or just my imagination.

Comment: @Matt, can you please specify how to do that!?

Comment: `<cfdump var="#form#">` or to access each field individually you can output `#form['num1']#`

Comment: awesome, that works for the input variables. how about those static questions, how can i capture those without specification?

Comment: @Mike write them too as <input type="hidden" name="Question" value="what is 1+1?"/>. you can run the same 'dump' given by Matt here.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this so I tried something to see what would happen.  I started with this form:

```
<form action="formtarget.cfm" method="post">
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and this code in formtarget.cfm.

I typed "fred" and "barney" into the two textboxes and got an empty structure in formtarget.cfm.

Then I added

```
 name="x"
```

to the submit input.  formtarget.cfm then displayed a structure with two keys, fieldnames and x.

So, the answer to, "is there a way I can pass this information, maybe by just using the form name, myform?", is "no, you have to name all your input fields".

The other answers and comments give you good suggestions on how to process these fields once you submit the form.

Comment: Yes, if you look over the [html specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) they say only "successful controls" should be submitted. One of the criteria for successful controls is that the field/element must have a `name`.